# why does the okhttp program dosen`t stucked in while(true)?

Tags: java, android

Recently i am reading the source code in OKHTTP and found that in RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java has a while(true) recycle. But, the program dose not stacked in that place or occur 'Application not responding'.Then I attached the debugger and put a breakpoint in that place and found it is running in main thread.I don`t know why the program runs normal at all.Who can help me? 
Thanks to stephenC`s answer, but you might not get my point.In my question I mean why does the program not stuck in while(true) recycle in main thread.
For example, if there is a while(true) recycle in activity`s onCreate() lifecycle, the app might not run correctly ,just stuck in that place and can not respond touch event, which means the application not responding(ANR).
How will the recycle exit?
The following is the source code:

```
@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    ...
    //This is the start of the recycle!Just recycle forever
    while (true) {
      if (canceled) {
        streamAllocation.release();
        throw new IOException("Canceled");
      }

      Response response;
      boolean releaseConnection = true;
      try {
        response = realChain.proceed(request, streamAllocation, null, null);
        releaseConnection = false;
      } catch (RouteException e) {
        // The attempt to connect via a route failed. The request will not have been sent.
        if (!recover(e.getLastConnectException(), streamAllocation, false, request)) {
          throw e.getFirstConnectException();
        }
        releaseConnection = false;
        continue;
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // An attempt to communicate with a server failed. The request may have been sent.
        boolean requestSendStarted = !(e instanceof ConnectionShutdownException);
        if (!recover(e, streamAllocation, requestSendStarted, request)) throw e;
        releaseConnection = false;
        continue;
      } finally {
        // We're throwing an unchecked exception. Release any resources.
        if (releaseConnection) {
          streamAllocation.streamFailed(null);
          streamAllocation.release();
        }
...
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.  The word "stacked" does not make sense here.  Do you mean "stuck"?   And what does ANR mean?  ("dosen't" means "doesn't" or "does not" ... I get that.  But you should use a straight quote - `'` - because a back-tick - `\`` - messes up the formatting.)

Comment: Thanks a lot .I will amend the question again.

Comment: You are still using back-ticks in your question.  Look at the formatting, and read the formatting help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about this:

```
    if (!recover(e.getLastConnectException(), streamAllocation, false, request)) {
      throw e.getFirstConnectException();
    }
    releaseConnection = false;
    continue;
```

or the similar code for `IOException`, the `recover(...)` call tests to see if failed request is recoverable.  (See the method for what that actually means.  But one of the criteria is that there is an alternative route that has not been tried yet.)  If the call returns `true`, then the `intercept` method will retry.  If it returns `false` then the relevant exception is rethrown.

In general, the logic in class is complicated, but it needs to be.  And it **clearly does work**.  So maybe you just need to read / study more of the context to understand what is happening.

Note that using a debugger to trace this could be difficult because the behavior is liable to change due to timeouts happening differently and altering the normal flow of control.  Consider that possibility ...

---

**UPDATE**

> How will the recycle exit?

It is called a loop, not a recycle.

As I have explained above, the particular loop paths that you highlighted will terminate (by rethrowing an exception) if the `recover(...)` call returns `false`. Let us take a look at `recover`.

```
  private boolean recover(IOException e, boolean routeException, Request userRequest) {
    streamAllocation.streamFailed(e);

    // The application layer has forbidden retries.
    if (!client.retryOnConnectionFailure()) return false;

    // We can't send the request body again.
    if (!routeException && userRequest.body() instanceof UnrepeatableRequestBody) return false;

    // This exception is fatal.
    if (!isRecoverable(e, routeException)) return false;

    // No more routes to attempt.
    if (!streamAllocation.hasMoreRoutes()) return false;

    // For failure recovery, use the same route selector with a new connection.
    return true;
  }
```

The first statement is doing some cleanup on the `StreamAllocation` object.  It isn't relevant to this.

The rest of the method is testing various things:

- The application layers forbids retries, it says don't retry.
- If a request was sent and it is not a resendable request, it says don't retry.
- If the exception indicates an error that won't be fixed by retrying, it says don't retry.
- If the route selector has no more routes to try, it says don't retry.
- Otherwise it says retry.  Next time that `proceed` is called, it will try the next route from the route selector.

Note that eventually it will run out of alternative routes to try.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply guy!Does the exception will be thrown definitely?I have reviewed the program and found that the 'recover' function will be called when an exception is caught.But how will the program run if there is no exception?

Comment: Review the code again.  If there is no exception at that point, the next thing that happens is that `intercept` tests to see if a followup request is needed (e.g. a redirect).  If "no", then the response is returned.  If there have been too many followups, then `intercept` ends with an exception.  Otherwise it starts working on the followup.